# Getting Section Code Value

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I'm trying to get a section's code value. The API call I'm using is `/d2l/api/lp/1.4/(orgUnitId)/sections/`.

For [sections](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/enroll.html#sections), It seems the API takes in Code as an attribute when creating and updating, but doesn't return it when fetching. Is my understanding correct? How do I get a section's code value?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the call to create a Section requires you to provide a `Code` property (the org-defined code for the new section), but the call you refer to for retrieving the section's properties back does not give it back to you. However, you can view the org-defined ID for any org unit with the more general call to retrieve [the properties of an org unit](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/orgunit.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28version%29-orgstructure-%28orgUnitId%29) which sends back an [OrgUnit JSON structure](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/orgunit.html#OrgUnit.OrgUnit).